Wiremock-pact-generator not adding providerStates
I am trying to use the wiremock-pact-generator library to generate a pact file for our wiremock tests; However, when I run the test file and generate the pact the providerStates field is not present in the pact. When I downloaded the wiremock-pact-generator repo I see the schema shows that providerStates is apart of the schema, just not required. When I change that to required and rebuild the jar and use that it still doesn’t work.
When looking at the tests in the wiremock-pact-generator code, it generate that providerStates in the pact files generated by the tests.
What am I doing wrong?
I have implemented the wiremock-pact-generator as shown in the documentation and it generates exactly as I want it to minus the providerStates field that is already implemented in the library.

Unfortunately the wiremock-pact-generator hasn't been updated in a long time and has a PR from 2019 to add providerState.  It looks like this library could have been abandond.  There is a newer pact wiremock extension that has just been released.  Not sure if this will solve your problem but might be worth looking at - https://github.com/tomasbjerre/wiremock-pact

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
